# Push notification is not received in windows phone app

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement push notification for windows phone using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3.

I  downloaded the push notification sample application from the ibm developer page [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/#projectSetupAndGuidelines), and installed it on my device. I am trying to use unauthenticated MPNS.

I am able to send the notification to an Android app by calling the adapter but not to windows app. the MobileFirst Console shows the number of messages sent but none of them are received.

do i need to submit my app in the windows developer console to use unauthenticated push notification

Below is the log from the visual studio.

'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: No, you do not need to submit the app during development... please supply the log from Visual Studio. Also mention which type of notification you are sending (event source, tag).

Comment: submitNotification(userId, notificationText){
var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId); if (userSubscription==null){return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };}
 var badgeDigit = 1;
 var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});
 WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);
 WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
 return {result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId};
}

Comment: this is the function that I am using to send the notification.and i have installed the app on a windows device. to test the notification

Comment: I asked for the log from the Output view in Visual Studio when the device is connected to the PC, not for the code from the sample application. Please edit the question and do not put this info in comments - there is an edit button...

Comment: i have edited my question with the log

Comment: Is this log from the time of the error? There is nothing valuable in it. Make sure you select the logs when the device is running and you attempt to send a notification. Also clarify whether it works if the app is open or doesn't work at all, no matter if the app is open or closed.

Comment: I tried it again using the emulator and the reinstalled the device again.when the app is open the alerts from the pushNotificationReceived methor are fired. but when the app is closed the notification does not appear in the notification bar

Comment: Did you alter the app in any way? Please upload your application to dropbox so we could debug it.

Comment: here is the link  https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0gxitue3froihc/PushNotificationsProject.rar?dl=0

Comment: Checked it again on the emulator and the device .have found that the payload has some data where as the props seems to be empty only when the app in open and in the foreground.

Comment: Idan can you also tell me how do I implement custom authentication for the push notification as mentioned in PushAppRealmChallengeHandler.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPNS notifications has 3 types -

1) raw

2) toast

3) tile

The application must be in foreground to handle raw notifications. Toast notifications are short, text-based messages that appear at the top of the phone's display. Tile notifications can modify the appearance of application tiles user has pinned to the Quick Launch area of their device.

The output JSON of WL.Server.createDefaultNotification() , contains a raw and tile payload and no toast payload. This is why you notice pushNotificationReceived() firing and see the push payload, when application is in foreground.

Since the default JSON does not contain a toast payload, you will NOT see a toast , when your application is in background. If you did have a tile pinned to your quick launch area, you should have seen the tile notification.

To get a toast notification modify the code slightly -

```
var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"}); 

notification.MPNS.toast = {};
notification.MPNS.toast.text1 = "Toast title";
notification.MPNS.toast.text2 = "Toast content";
```

To see a tile notification , pin your application to the quick launch area , put the application to background and then try sending the notification.

API and output JSON details can be found [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23createDefaultNotification) :